# How check elasticsearch unique document

Tags: elasticsearch, constraints, unique, document

As I understand it, ES can't create unique constraints on index.
But, on creation and updating of the documents, I need to check that some fields are unique in index.
Can ES find **matches of content**, not a query? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you've updated your record you'd have to run a query to find how many others have that field value.  Something like:

```
GET index1/test/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "field123": 10
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note the size of zero, this will save time by not returning any records, but it will still return you the *total* number of records matching.